# Turn Django project into MVC(Model, View, Control) Structure by move all the apps model, view file in different folder

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I want to Change my project structure so that my project follows MVC structure.

**Currently my project Structure:**

- My_Ecom_project

  - App_Login

    - admin.py
    - apps.py
    - forms.py
    - models.py
    - urls.py
    - views.py
  - App_Order

    - admin.py
    - ....
    - views.py
  - App_Shop

    - ....
  - My_Ecom_Project

    - *init*.py
    - settings.py
    - urls.py
    - wsgi.py
  - static

    - ...
  - templates

    - ...
  - mange.py

**I want to change this to:**

- My_Ecom_project

  - App_Login

    - admin.py
    - apps.py
    - forms.py
    - models.py
    - urls.py
    - views.py
  - App_Order

    - admin.py
    - ....
    - views.py
  - App_Shop

    - ....
  - MVC Structure  `*****Add MVC Structure folder here****`

    - Model

      - App_Login

        - models.py
      - App_Order

        - models.py
    - View

      - Templates
    - Controller

      - App_Login

        - views.py
      - App_Order

        - views.py
  - My_Ecom_Project

    - *init*.py
    - settings.py
    - urls.py
    - wsgi.py
  - static

    - ...
  - templates

    - ...
  - manage.py

I want to add a MVC Structure folder like above and keep all models.py in a model folder, views.py in controller folder, templates in view folder

Comment: I'd first ask yourself _why_ you want to deviate from the standard project structure, then consider whether this is worth your time. Django is a convention over configuration framework, in my own opinion, so deviating from conventions like project structures will only make your life more difficult.

Comment: Thank you for your concern. I have to do this for practicing MVC architecture on demand of my supervisor.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the way to do it and I am posting this answer if someone may need it in future. All the steps that I have followed to achieve the MVC Structure:

1. Firstly, I have created a project using django-admin command.
2. Then I created 'MVC Structure' folder in main project folder.

   ```
                `****************View*****************`
   ```
3. I have created a 'View' folder into it and keep all my static, media, templates there.
4. Also, create forms.py  and create a **init**.py file in View folder.
5. In settings.py add static, media and templates directory path accordingly.
6. Then created an App called Model using py manage.py startapp Model Command.

   ```
                 `****************Model*****************`
   ```
7. Move the app into 'MVC Structure' folder.
8. On the settings.py add "MVC Structure.Model" to the array called "Installed_Apps"
9. Now, keep all model related code into the Model apps models.py file.
10. As MVC Structure folder have space in it's name, I used **import** function to import module or packages.
11. After doing all the things in models.py and admin.py, I did the migrations for controller app.

    ```
              `****************Controller*****************`
    ```
12. The I have create another app called Controller and do all the step from 5 to 7.
13. After that, I keep all view code  into the Controller app views.py file.
14. I successfully change the whole structure from MVT to MVC Architecture.

Import things from different app or folder:
_models = **import**("MVC Structure.Model.models")
_models = _models.Model.models

Now, I can use _models variable for working with any model. For instance: _models.User
Same goes for forms, views or any other module.